# How to set yearly jobs in Sql Server Agent

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to add 12 credits to 2 columns of a table. I want to do this every 6 months.
But there seem to be no such option in Job Schedule Properties.

Also, what should be the job statement if I want to show a log of credits and debits to the admin. Explained better at:

**EDIT :**
 Having solved half the problem, here is the other half of it.

The admin should be shown a record of the credit and debit of leaves taking place in each user account, like a log. How do I show this in a gridview or table or any way? 
Example, when admin logs in and selects an employee name to view their leave balance-sheet, it should look something like below

[image]

Now, the admin should be able to add leaves when an employee cashes his leaves,by clicking on the Credit Leaves button. ALSO, yearly log should be displayed and on changing year, that year's log should be displayed.

Please give me some idea about what should be the steps for this server agent job.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here with a SQL Server Agent job.  You're talking about this very much from the point of view of a front end application.  e.g. When admin logs in, clicks on a button, etc.  Are there some stored procedures you want to schedule via the agent?  What exactly do you need done?  Also, I would suggest that you open this on a new thread.  Especially since having marked this one as answered already, you probably won't get as much traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the sound advice @ScubaManDan. I have made a new question and tried to explain better there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793734/how-do-i-show-balance-log-in-a-gridview Could you help me here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the first day of every 6 months starting from January:

[image: On the first day of every 6 months starting from January]

Comment: Please see the updated question and the other problem explained in it.

Answer (score 4):

Set the first day of every 12 months.

It is second option under selected dropdown list.

Comment: I can not do that. It is required that on 1st jan and 1st july, the user be reflected updated number of leaves. I can not keep crediting two for each month.

Comment: They're six months apart.  Why not just set it to the first day of every 6 months, starting from January.  You've got two radio buttons in the Frequency section there.  You should be able to do this after selecting the second one, instead of the first one you're using in your image.

Comment: I've added a screenshot, which is what Anton was essentially saying.